# [__NSCFString name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsindexpath

odd issue, my application has a UITableView with three sections, each populated by a separate array. The end-goal is to have the ability to move cells from section to section, so I wrote the 'logic' in the UITableViewController. Unfortunately, if I try to move a cell into an empty section, it crashes with the error `[__NSCFString name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. I cannot figure out the flaw in my code, so I thought I'd bring it here instead of spending more hours debugging in the wrong direction.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {




    if (sourceIndexPath.section == 0) {
     Athlete *athlete = players[sourceIndexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"sta count: %lu", (unsigned long)[players count]);
        if (athlete != nil) {

        if (destinationIndexPath.section == 1) {
                [players removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
                 [benched insertObject:athlete.name atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
        }else if (destinationIndexPath.section == 2){

            [players removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];

                 [reserved insertObject:athlete.name atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
        }
        }
    } else if (sourceIndexPath.section == 1) {
    Athlete *athlete = benched[sourceIndexPath.row];
           NSLog(@"Benched count: %lu", (unsigned long)[benched count]);
        if (destinationIndexPath.section == 0) {

            [benched removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];

            [players insertObject:athlete.name atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
        }else if (destinationIndexPath.section == 2){

            [benched removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];

            [reserved insertObject:athlete.name atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
        }
    }else if (sourceIndexPath.section == 2) {
          Athlete *athlete = reserved[sourceIndexPath.row];
           NSLog(@"Res count: %lu", (unsigned long)[reserved count]);
        NSLog(@"From starter");
        if (destinationIndexPath.section == 1) {
            NSLog(@"To bench");
            [reserved removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
            [benched insertObject:athlete.name atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
        }else if (destinationIndexPath.section == 0){
            NSLog(@"To reserves");
            [reserved removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];

            [players insertObject:athlete.name atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];

    }





   /* [players removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [players insertObject:athlete.name atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];*/


    }



}
```

Notes:
* All of the NSMutableArrays are `(nonatomic, retain)`.
* The exact line of failure is the `[NSMutableArray insertObject:athlete.name atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row];`.
* `Athlete *athlete` is an object with NSString properties, like `athlete.name`.

Comment: so `athlete` is `NSString` instead of `Athlete`

Comment: @BryanChen athlete is an NSObject with 'assigned properties', like athlete.name is an NSString, athlete isn't an NSString.

Comment: thats what you expecting, but apparently not happening otherwise you won't see that error.

Comment: @BryanChen, which is  odd, I setup a check in the first 'if' block (if athlete != nil). What might be happening is the athlete object has no properties, but I cannot see how that could happen.

Comment: just `NSLog("%@ - %@", [athlete class], athlete)`

Comment: @BryanChen ok, very odd, from a 'filled' section to another 'filled' section, it returned 'Athlete - <Athlete: 0x1742bd820>' but then from a 'filled' section to an empty one, it returned __NSCFString - Kevin Durant

Comment: @BryanChen got it now, thanks a lot man. How can I give you 'points' for walking me though it. I should've logged a lot more than I did, it was a dumb issue. I should've been inserting athlete not athlete.name into the array. Sometimes it just helps to talk it out for a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying you are trying to call `name` method on `NSString`.

This means you have an `athlete` that is `NSString` instead of `Athlete`.

You can check the object type in debugger or use `NSLog("%@ - %@", [athlete class], athlete)` to log it.

Comment: You tha man! Have a great day/night/evening/morning/afternoon.